# The upper bound for the expectation

Tags: probability

I am struggling to get an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[\gamma^{-a}]$, where $a$ is a positive random variable and fixed $0<\gamma<1$.

When we know $\mathbb{E}[a] = c$, is there any possible way to get the upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[\gamma^{-a}]$?

Comment: Do we know anything about the distribution of `a`? Is it normally distributed? If not, I'm guessing you can't upper bound the expectation of the modified distribution. Also, is it guaranteed that gamma to the -a is actually a probability distribution for all values of gamma?

Comment: @barrycarter Thank you for your comment. I don't know the distribution of $a$. If it is confused, we can assume just gamma = 0.5.  How about when we have $a_n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(a_n \ge C \text{ i.o. }) = 0$ instead $a$? Then, with fixed large enough N, can we have an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[\gamma^{-a_N}$] ?